# Find files created in specific months in multiple years

Tags: macos, unix, search, find

In OS X - gui or cli

I'd like to find files created in specific months over a series of years.

Ex. All mp3s file created in April in the years 1998-2012

suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it with touch files and find and post-process with awk

```
touch -t 199801010000.01 startfile
touch -t 201212312359.59 endfile
find /path/to/mp3dir -type f -iname "*.mp3" -newer startfile -not -newer endfile -ls | awk '{ if ($8 == "Apr") print }'
```